# Reorder array compared to another array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have one array in Swift containing some ids of objects, and I have another array containing these objects with their ids, so something like this:

```
class MyObject {
   let id: String
   ...
}

let ids: [String] = ...
let objects: [MyObject] = ...
```

Now the array of ids is sorted in some custom order, and I need the array of objects to be sorted in the same order. So for example:

```
let ids: [String] = ["1", "2", "3"]
let objects: [MyObject] = [obj3, obj1, obj2]
// obj1.id = "1"
// obj2.id = "2"
// obj3.id = "3"
objects.reorder(template: ids) 
// Now objects = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
```

So I basically need to implement this reorder method. 
Does anyone have a smart suggestion how to do this in Swift? I'm using Swift 3, so all the new APIs are available to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can sort `objects` in order to follow the order in `ids` writing

```
let sorted = objects.sort { ids.indexOf($0.id) < ids.indexOf($1.id) }
// [{id "1"}, {id "2"}, {id "3"}]
```

### Another example

```
let ids: [String] = ["3", "2", "1"]
let objects: [MyObject] = [MyObject(id: "3"), MyObject(id: "1"), MyObject(id: "2")]

let sorted = objects.sort { ids.indexOf($0.id) < ids.indexOf($1.id) }
// [{id "3"}, {id "2"}, {id "1"}]
```

> This code is in Swift 2.2

---

Swift 4.2 solution

```
let sorted = objects.sorted { ids.index(of: $0.id)! < ids.index(of: $1.id)! }
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: In Swift 3 this would be `let sorted = objects.sorted { ids.index(of: $0.id)! < ids.index(of: $1.id)! }`

Comment: @Banana's solution works for Swift 4 as well, could possibly make it's way into the accepted answer

Comment: @DylanReich I just added it.

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution:

```
let sorted = objects.flatMap { obj in
    ids.index(of: obj.id).map { idx in (obj, idx) }
}.sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 } ).map { $0.0 }
```

Explanation:

- First, each object is tied to together with the corresponding 
  position of the id in the array, this gives an array of 
  `(object, index)` tuples.
- This array is sorted with respect to the index positions.
- Finally, the objects are extracted again.

Possible advantages:

- Each object is searched only once in the array.
- Objects for which no id exists in the array are ignored.

Comment: This is probably the best solution (albeit a little hard to understand at first glance) – note that the inner `flatMap` could just be a regular `map` as the tuple returned is non-optional :)

Comment: @Hamish: You are right, thanks. – `indexOf` returns an optional, but `map` is sufficient to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a computer science person, but it seems to me that this business of repeatedly calling `indexOf` is wasteful. Surely the right approach would be to walk through the template array (`ids` in this case) once in advance, building a dictionary that associates each element with its position in the array:

```
let ids = ["1", "2", "3"]
var d = [String:Int]()
for (ix,id) in ids.enumerated() {
    d[id] = ix
}
```

Now we've got a dictionary, and lookup in a dictionary is fast. So we can use each object's `id` as the key and sort on the corresponding value. Let's say that this is our initial array of objects:

```
class MyObject {
    let id: String
    init(id:String) {self.id = id}
}
let objects = [MyObject(id:"3"), MyObject(id:"1"), MyObject(id:"2")]
```

Now sorting is a one-liner:

```
let objectsSorted = objects.sorted { d[$0.id]! < d[$1.id]! }
```

The advantage here is especially obvious if you know you're going to be using `ids` as a template often, because you only have to form the dictionary `d` *once* and now you're ready to sort against that template as many times as you like. In effect, the dictionary memoizes the sort order. (Granted, I have not taken into account what happens if the dictionary lookup were to fail; we just crash.)

---

We can generalize that approach, based on the fact that in order to serve as a dictionary key, the values in the template array must be hashable:

```
struct Cosorter<K:Hashable> {
    let d : [K:Int]
    init(_ arr:[K]) {
        var dd = [K:Int]()
        for (ix,val) in arr.enumerated() {
            dd[val] = ix
        }
        self.d = dd
    }
    func lt(_ v1:K, _ v2:K) -> Bool {
        return self.d[v1]! < self.d[v2]!
    }
}
```

Now each template is transformed into a Cosorter instance initialized with the template array, thus causing the dictionary to be prepared, once:

```
let idsTemplate = Cosorter(ids)
```

Any time we want to cosort on that template, we just use that template's `lt` as the ordering function:

```
let objectsSorted = objects.sorted {idsTemplate.lt($0.id,$1.id)}
```

Answer (score -1):

Be aware that the reorder method fails if the id could not be found in `unsorted`

```
func reorder(items: [MyObject], order : [String]) -> [String] {
    var unsorted = items
    var ordered : [String] = []
    for orderId in order {
        let index = unsorted.filter{ $0.id == orderId }.first
        let found = unsorted.remove(at: index!)
        ordered.append(found)
    }
    return ordered
}
```