# Sort String array by Int Array

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to order an array with the help of another, like this:

```
var names = [anna, berta, caesar, dora]
var sorting = [2, 0, 1, 3]
```

to be sorted like this:

```
var sortedNames = [caesar, anna, berta, dora]
```

so that the Integer array ("sorting") sorts the String array ("names") after its own values. How can I do that?

I tried it with a for loop, but it didn't worked.

```
for i in 0...names.count
{
    let x = "\(names[sorting]])"

    sortedNames.append(x)
}
return history
```

Comment: What is the type of `names`? is it array of strings?

Comment: Are the indices in the seconds array always a permutation of the first arrays's indices?

Comment: See also [Reorder array compared to another array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273370/reorder-array-compared-to-another-array-in-swift).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `map()` function to transform the values of `sorting`:

```
var names = ["anna", "berta", "caesar", "dora"]
var sorting = [2, 0, 1, 3]

let sortedNames = sorting.map({ names[$0] }) // ["caesar", "anna", "berta", "dora"]
```

> Keep in mind that this solution only works if the values in `sorting` are valid indices for the `names` array.

Comment: Simple and elegant. You don't even need the parentheses: `sorting.map { names[$0] }`

Comment: Typical. Keep in mind that if the second `sorting` array contains a number that is *not* a valid index for the first array, you would get "Fatal error: Index out of range".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object which has properties the names and sorting

```
var name: String!
var sorting: Int!
```

Then you can easily sort your array of objects like this

```
array.sort(by: {$0.sorting<$1.sorting})
```

In this way you will have for each name sorting value and it will be pretty easy to do any manipulations with it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help! Will try it

Comment: @dionizb Very elegant solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

> var names = [anna, berta, caesar, dora]
>
> var sorting = [2, 0, 1, 3]

Simple approach with `for loop` is to select the values from `sorting` array and treat them as index to get respective value from `names` array.

```
var sortedNames = [String]()
for i in 0..<sorting.count {
    let x = sortedNames[i]
    sortedNames.append(x)
}   
return sortedNames // [caesar, anna, berta, dora]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, will try it:

Comment: @Ankit please add some context regarding your answer, it will help for future readers.