# Swift Arrays: Keeping the order while filtering an array using another

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, filtering

I have an array as a list of numbers. In another smaller array I hold some numbers (in a different order) and I'd like to filter my first array using the values in the second array.

**My arrays:**

```
let allNumbers = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190, 200]
let someNumbers = [100, 90, 120, 200] // unordered
```

When I use `filter` method or loop through the values of the first array, I can get the correct values but the order of the elements is not same with my second array but the first -naturally.

**Method 1:** `filter` method, losing order

```
let filtered = allNumbers.filter { someNumbers.contains($0) } // Runs 17 times
print(filtered) // "[90, 100, 120, 200]" (wrong order)
```

**Method 2:** Looping through first array, losing order

```
var filteredWithLoop: [Int] = []
for number in allNumbers { // Runs 16 Times
    if someNumbers.contains(number) {
        filteredWithLoop.append(number)
    }
}
print(filteredWithLoop) // "[90, 100, 120, 200]" (wrong order)
```

**Hack:** I can work this around by filtering the first array when I'm looping through the second, like this:

```
var filteredUglyWay: [Int] = []
for number in someNumbers {
    if let alone = (allNumbers.filter { $0 == number }).first { // Runs 4 * 16 Times
        filteredUglyWay.append(alone)
    }
}
print(filteredUglyWay) // "[100, 90, 120, 200]" (correct order)
```

But this feels more like a hack rather than a solution to me especially considering that the loop-ish filter method is called in a loop.

Is there a better approach for this or is this just how it's supposed to be?

**Important note:** The first array is actually a representation to make the situation more understandable. In my real implementation, first array is holding some objects and the second array is just the ID list of some objects (like favorites of the user) so each time I fetch the whole data, I am trying to filter the favorite objects according to this ID list.

Comment: Method1/2, what about inversing the two arrays? `let filtered = someNumbers.filter { allNumbers.contains($0) }`

Comment: Line1: let combined = zip(self.leavelistdatearr, self.leavelistnamearr).sorted {$0.0 < $1.0}
                    print(combined)
                    
                    // use map to extract the individual arrays
                  Line2:  let sorted1 = combined.map {$0.0}
                  Line3: let sorted2 = combined.map {$0.1}
                  Line4:  self.leavelistdatearr = sorted1
                  Line5:  self.leavelistnamearr = sorted2

Comment: @Larme Edited the question, the first array is actually a representation. In my code it is holding some custom objects instead of plain numbers so I am trying to filter those objects according to my second (let's say, favorites) array.

Comment: Is filtering, then sorting a viable solution? Something like: `let filtered = allNumbers.filtered({ someNumbers.contains($0)}).sorted({someNumbers.index(of:$0)!})`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273370/reorder-array-compared-to-another-array-in-swift

Comment: @Larme To satisfy the Swift 4 compiler, it's actually like this: `let final = filtered.sorted(by: { someNumbers.index(of: $0)! < someNumbers.index(of: $1)! })`. Thanks for the idea, could you please post this as an answer so that I can approve?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the other part of the sort, since logically the sort closure compare 2 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution: 
Filter, then sort.

```
let filtered = allNumbers.filtered({ someNumbers.contains($0) })
let filteredAndSorted = filtered.sorted(by: { someNumbers.index(of: $0)! < someNumbers.index(of: $1)! })
```

Side note, since `filtered` is composed of data only in `someNumbers`, the fore unwrap shouldn't create a crash.

Answer (score 0):

why not to try updated method 2

**Method 2 UPDATED**: Looping through second array

```
var filteredWithLoop: [Int] = []
    for number in someNumbers { // Runs 4 Times
        if allNumbers.contains(number) {
            filteredWithLoop.append(number)
        } // IF OBJECT IS NOT THERE IN FIRST ARRAY IT WILL BE AUTOMATICALLY DISCARDED
    }
    print(filteredWithLoop) // "[100, 90, 120, 200]" (proper order)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
let filtered = someNumbers.filter { allNumbers.contains($0) }
print(filtered) // Prints [100, 90, 120, 200]
```

It's probably less efficient when allNumbers is much larger than someNumbers, but if efficiency isn't an issue here, it seems like this is the most neat solution to me.