# Sort an array of objects, following the order of another array that has a value of the objects of the first array

Tags: swift, sorting

How could I sort an array of objects taking into account another array?

Example:

```
let sortArray = [90, 1000, 4520]
```

```
let notSortArrayObject = [ { id: 4520, value: 4 }, {id: 1000, value: 2}, {id: 90, value:10} ]
```

So I want an array equal notSortArrayObject but sortered by sortArray value

```
let sortArrayObject =[{id: 90, value:10} , {id: 1000, value: 2}, { id: 4520, value: 4 }]
```

Comment: `let sorted = notSortArrayObject.sorted(by: { sortArray.firstIndex(of: $0.id) ?? Int.max < sortArray.firstIndex(of: $1.id) ?? Int.max })` should do the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reorder array compared to another array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273370/reorder-array-compared-to-another-array-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach. For each number in the "guide" array, find a match in the not sorted and add it to the `sortedObjectArray`. Note that this ignores any values which don't have matches in the other array.

```swift
var sortedObjectArray: [Object] = [] // whatever your object type is

for num in sortArray {
    if let match = notSortArrayObject.first(where: {$0.id == num}) {
        sortedObjectArray.append(match)
    }
}
```

If you just want to sort by the `id` in ascending order, it's much simpler:

```
let sorted = notSortArrayObject.sorted(by: {$0.id < $1.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `sortArray` is already sorted - you could just sort `notSortArrayObject` by `id`, but I assume that's not the point of what you're looking for.

So, let's say that `sortArray = [1000, 4520, 90]` (random order), to make things more interesting.

You can iterate through `sortArray` and append the values that match the `id` to `sortArrayObject`.

```
            // To store the result
            var sortArrayObject = [MyObject]()
            
            // Iterate through the elements that contain the required sequence
            sortArray.forEach { element in
                
                // Add only the objects (only one) that match the element
                sortArrayObject += notSortArrayObject.filter { $0.id == element }
            }
```