# How to get NSSortDescriptor to sort based on array order?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have an array of object IDs and the array has the correct order.

```
let objectsIDs = [504, 316, 195, ...]
```

And I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` with this `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate(format: "%K IN %@", #keyPath(object.id), objectsIDs)
```

`NSFetchedResultsController` requires `NSSortDescriptor` and I cannot use `createdAt` or `id` property to sort the objects.

How can I get `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the objects based on the `objectsIDs` array order? The `objectsIDs` array always have the correct order and `NSSortDescriptor` must depend on its order.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get NSSortDescriptor to sort the objects based on the objectsIDs array order?

You can't. What you're trying to do is *cosort* the array, ie sort it according to the order of another array. NSSortDescriptor doesn't do that. *You* have to do it. Cosorting is a well discussed problem.

Comment: Do you have suggestions on how I can do this? Adding a dedicated property to the `NSManagedObject` subclass is not practical for me as I have various scenarios where the order is different.

Comment: You just have to get the data in any old order and then sort. It's not going to come to you sorted from the fetch. That's my point.

Comment: Examples for Swift of how to cosort: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39273370/reorder-array-compared-to-another-array-in-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43056807/sorting-a-swift-array-by-ordering-from-another-array You can readily do the same in Objective-C.

Comment: Right, I see but these are regular arrays. I use `NSFetchedResultsController` and it depends on `NSSortDescriptor` to sort the objects. Is there another way to configure `NSFetchedResultsController` to sort the objects without `NSSortDescriptor`?

Comment: Thanks. A lot of these are written in Objective-C and I did not find anything that were relevant to me. I was thinking about what you said that I have to sort them myself as I can't get them sorted. So I could do the sorting in `controller(_:didChangeContentWith:)` as part of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Sorry, somehow I had the impression that you wanted Objective-C.